# Each item has one button to add quantities to another order list. Offset is not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have one Command Buttons been set up for each product line. Totally, I have more than 20 buttons on Sheet 1.

If I click any of them with quantity more than 1, the product name will be copied and pasted to Order List sheet.

I try to use the Offset to paste it to blank column under line A from A2 in Order List.

However, it is only replacing A2 rather than paste to A3 after I click another button.

Code details for first two buttons are as following (all 20 buttons should be same code, as they will not be clicked in order. As long as it picks up the blank column, it should be fine):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")  
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Order List")

    'Stop if report not filled in fully
    If wsSource.Range("G28").Value < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please Amend Quantity"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    wsSource.Range("B28").Copy wsDest.Range("A1").Offset(1,0)
    wsDest.Range("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")  
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Order List")

    'Stop if report not filled in fully
    If wsSource.Range("G28").Value < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please Amend Quantity"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    wsSource.Range("B28").Copy wsDest.Range("A1").Offset(1,0)
    wsDest.Range("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Please advise me. Many thanks

Comment: You're always going to be putting data into A2, because you're always starting at A1. You need to find the last used row + 1 in each routine and paste data there. Like `Range("A" & lastRow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead which will find the last used cell and then move down to the next cell (your code never updates the destination cell, it is fixed at A2). What sort of buttons are these - you should be able to avoid repeating your code 20 times.

```
wsSource.Range("B28").Copy wsDest.Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).Offset(1,0)
```